# How to type async function passed as prop to React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How should I type an async function that I'm passing to my React component as a property?

My component is defined below. Specifically I don't know how to type the **addTask** property in my interface:

```
interface INewTaskEntryProps {
    addTask:any; // this 
}
class NewTaskEntry extends React.Component<INewTaskEntryProps> {
    ...
    render() { 
        return (
            ...
            <button onClick={(e) => this.props.addTask(e)}>Do Something</button>
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

And my async function is defined like so:

```
const addTask = async (e) => {
    ...
    try {
        const newID = await mongoTaskCollection.insertOne({
            ...
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

And finally I pass the async function into my component like so:

```
<NewTaskEntry addTask={addTask} />
```

Comment: `(e: EventType) => Promise<void>`

Comment: On the most recent React version, I know its `const addTask = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => ...` . Not sure about your older version.

Comment: @SILENT that's correct for creating the callback but he's trying to specify the type of such a value independently from creating one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on what addTask returns but can be something like this:

```js
interface INewTaskEntryProps {
  addTask: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => Promise<void>; 
}
```

In this case you are telling `addTask` returns a promise that resolve null value. If your fn returns the mongo document and you have it typed you can add that (like `Promise<Task>`) instead of `void` as the return value.

Comment: We know that `addTask` returns `Promise<T>` and `void` is the most likely candidate for `T` because it's an event handler. Your event type is correct though I believe

Comment: Perfect! Also I should have realized this was the answer - the Typescript error in my browser literally had this exact recommendation in it. :)